# Links Purple Despite CSS Override

Tags: css

I have a link on my web page. I have it set to this in the CSS:

```
a:link {
    color:#6F0 !important;
}
```

However, when you look at it online, it comes up as a purple color. I just can not figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks,

Michael K.

Comment: It might just be for the simple fact that you have already visited that link before … and that for `a:visited` there’s a different color defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a:link` is only for normal, unvisited links. There are a couple of flavours that you need to take care of, most notably `a:visited`.

- a:link - a normal, unvisited link
- a:visited - a link the user has visited
- a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
- a:active - a link the moment it is clicked

Since the default style sheet will have a different (purple) color for at least the visited link, I would reset all of them with:

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
  color: #6f0;
}
```

See also: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 0):

Purple denotes that it is a visited link. Try this:

```css
a {color: #6f0;}
```

If not, try this:

```css
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active {color: #6f0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a:visited {} or a:active{}